# Obfuscate Android Source Code

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

Salam, I have a complete source code, but I want to make an obfuscated .apk. I have read all topics, but this didn't help me. Please help! I am using eclipse for development. Here is the details about my app.

```
Android SDK folder : C:\Android\android-sdk-windows<br>
Project  Folder    : C:\Android\workspace\HijriCalendar<br>
Ant Folder         : C:\Android\ant<br>
proguard folder    : C:\Android\proguard<br>
main activity      : hussain.Musaji.HijriCalendarActivity.java<br>
```

Please anyone tell me step by step procedure to make obfucated .apk

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not going to like my comment but [here it goes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3122640/1132648)

Comment: If you had read http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html carefully, you would have seen :"ProGuard is integrated into the Android build system, so you do not have to invoke it manually. ProGuard runs only when you build your application in release mode". Read it again, it tells you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing an Android application using Eclipse. But for building an obfuscated apk, it was more helpful to use the ant build instead. Here is what I recommend:

- Use the latest version of Proguard which may not be the one integrated in your Android SDK version. Install it wherever you want and add the following line to your `local.properties` file to use it: `proguard.jar=C:/yourpath_to_pg/lib/proguard.jar`.
- [This article](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html) gives a good overview on confugring proguard for Android applications.
- If you are using LVL for managing your applications's licensing, please refer to
  [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843093/how-to-turn-off-all-android-proguard-features-except-obfuscation).
- You may also use proguard when building your application in debug mode by invoking ant as follows:

  `> ant debug -Dproguard.enabled=true`

As Nunonix already mentioned, it may be helpful to see your `proguard.cfg` file.
Hope, this helps you.